# Error while connecting my azure vm through azure bastion

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

So , i created an azure bastion named "test" under the virtual network "RemoteAccess-Bastion-VN".Under this virtual network i also created a subnet "AzureBastionSubnet"  with "/27" range.And when i try to connect my VM through bastion i dont see my bastion , i am asked once again to create a new bastion.I dont know where i am wrong.I think i followed the steps correctly and now i am stuck.
[I have attached the pic showing how it looks when i try to connect through bastion , it should show the login credentials page but instead it is asking me to create a new bastion.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv8HS.png)

Thank You

Comment: It takes about 5 minutes for the Bastion resource to be created and deployed. Are you waiting for that time? If it is deployed well, you will see the notification on the portal.

Comment: I waited an entire day , still nothing to see any change

Comment: yes i can see my "test" bastion in my resource group.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, probably, the Azure Bastion service is not provision successfully. If it has been deployed well, you will see the **Bastion** type service in your resource group like this,
[image]

Also, from your Virtual machine---Operations---Bastion, you will see the provision status.
[image]

You could follow this [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-create-host-portal#createhost) to create a bastion host. It takes about 5 minutes for the Bastion resource to be created and deployed. Let me know if you still have any question.

### **Edit**

In this case, you need to put the vm and the vnet in the **same region** and created a bastion in the vnet.

Comment: i have already created three bastions but none of them were of any help , i faced the same error.

Comment: It's wired. Do you clear the cache in the web explorer or change another explorer? Do you create bastion from creating a resource---new--bastion on the portal? What's your account's permission? Is the account an owner role in your subscription?

Comment: No ,  i didnt cleared the cache of the web browser and also i have been working on the same web browser.Yes , i created the bastion from the portal.How to check my account's permission? Also how to check which type of account i am using?

Comment: Click ctrl+F5 to refresh your browser? Check your permission from bastion---access control(IAM)---role assignment, search your account in the name box, you will see the role and scope mapping to your account.

Comment: the role is "contributor" and scope is "Subscription(inherited)"

Comment: Permission seems ok, Try to login in to your portal on another computer?

Comment: Do you check these: `Azure Bastion is currently available only in the following regions: West US, East US, West Europe, South Central US, Australia East, Japan East. It must be deployed in the same region as the vnet it is providing access to (that is, the same vnet that your VMs are using). `https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/azure-bastion-access-your-azure-virtual-servers-without-a-public/ba-p/737543#

Comment: any update? If still no luck, try to create a new vnet and VM and a new azure bastion host in that new vnet. all services are in the same region. Is the issue reproduced?

Comment: Yes , it worked finally.I put the vm and the vnet in the same region and created a bastion in the vnet.Thank you for your help and time , really appreciate it.